# Pass functor to compile-command

Tags: forms, elisp

I've created my own elisp function which calculates the `compile-command` string each time I want to compile a whole project (which has usually a makefile in the root of the project's directory tree) or a single file (which usually has no makefile and uses the make's implicit rules).

It allows me to find automatically the location of a recently created, renamed or moved makefile in the directory tree of a project, without having to close and reopen the editor to reload the file-local variables at the beginning of a project.

The Emacs' `compile` function implementation uses the expression `(let ((command (eval compile-command))) body)` in case `compile-command` is bound to a form (for instance, `compilation-read-command`, as stated in the `compile-command` documentation).

I want to take adventage of this to get a dynamic `compile-command` string, but I don't know how to create those "forms" encapsulating a function call, as required by `eval`. All the examples I've found in the emacs-lisp documentation about `eval` use simple variables, not function captures.

I've tried with something simple as `(setq-default compile-command 'my-compile-command-fun)`, but of course it didn't work.

`my-compile-command-fun` has no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ELISP> (defun foo () "bar")
foo

ELISP> (foo)
"bar"

ELISP> (eval '(foo))
"bar"
```

Therefore you presumably wanted this:

```
(setq-default compile-command '(my-compile-command-fun))
```

Comment: Yeah, I swear that I had already tested it and didn't work! But no, it seems that it works fine.

Comment: @Peregring-lk It works fine now, because `'(my-compile-command-fun)` is a list whereas 'my-compile-command-fun is a symbol. The former is equal to `(list 'my-compile-command-fun)`, whereas the latter is (roughly) equal to `(intern "my-compile-command-fun")`. Upon evaluation, the former turns into a function call, whereas the latter gives you the value of the function. To understand this better, try `(eval (list 'message "Hello world"))` :)